# Flask page not showing the content that it is supposed to show

Tags: python, flask

the post page must show the the post passed to it as well, but it is only displaying the layout inherited to it.

routes.py

```
@app.route("/post/<int:post_id>")
def post(post_id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    return render_template('post.html', title=post.title, post=post)
```

post.html

````
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
    <article class="media content-section">
            <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='pictures/' + post.author.image_file) }}">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">

              <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author.username }}</a>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2 class="article-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
          </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}```
````

Comment: How do you want it to display, and how does it display presently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require a for loop in the html page, replace your post.html from

```
{% block content %}
{% for post in posts %}
<article class="media content-section">
        <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='pictures/' + post.author.image_file) }}">
      <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">

          <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author.username }}</a>
          <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</small>
        </div>
        <h2 class="article-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
      </div>
    </article>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

to:

````
{% block content %}
    <article class="media content-section">
            <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='pictures/' + post.author.image_file) }}">
          <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">

              <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ post.author.username }}</a>
              <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2 class="article-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
          </div>
        </article>
   {% endblock content %}```
````

Answer (score 1):

When a template uses

```
{% for post in posts %}
```

it's expecting `posts` to be an Iterable (e.g., a list) that contains individual posts.

The route is passing the template a single post in `post`. Since the template isn't being passed `posts`, it will treat it as an empty list.

Remove the `for` loop, but not its contents.